# Google Poly alternative for 3D models API

Tags: api, unity-game-engine, 3d, google-poly

Inevitably (hasn't been updated since 2018) though sadly, Google Poly is closing down. :-(

Is there another 3D mesh API available? Ideally one that also works "out of the box" with Unity? Ideally with the option to filter by low-poly models and such...

Answer (score 2):

If you want free or non free 3d models for unity I want to suggest these websites:

**1. Cults 3D**

Cults offers its users the perfect range of 3D models – from maker-inspired 3D files all the way to professional high-quality designs. Cults checks each 3D design for printability and organizes them into different groups such as fashion, art, jewelry, home, architecture, or gadgets. The mix of a modern visual interface, a well-arranged database, and a focus on smart, useful & beautiful designs makes browsing through their website a lot of fun. While many models come for free, others come at very affordable prices.

**2. Pinshape**

Pinshape offers its visitors the opportunity to browse through a great selection of more than 13,000 (free and payable) STL files. Finding great 3D printable models on the website is child’s play: both the visual representation and logical organization of the website are top-notch.

**3. 3DShook**

The 3DShook website is somewhat similar to Pinshape and Cults but the designs tend to be more focused on ‘fun’ 3D prints for hobbyists. Some models are free but most require a fee. However, 3DShook does offer designs at a very competitive price.

**4. Thingiverse**

Thingiverse is probably one of the biggest and most popular databases. It has a very active maker community behind it and offers free-to-use STL files only. You don’t even need to open an account in order to download a 3D model from their site. Sometimes the database can seem slightly less organized than the cleaner and simpler design of sites like Pinshape and Cults.

**5. GrabCAD**

GrabCAD is different than the databases we have looked at so far. Firstly, GrabCad provides you with technical, engineering, and scale models only. Secondly, it lets you filter its database based on the 3D modeling software that the designs were created in. It’s the place to be for anyone looking for more than 27,000 technical 3D files. However, take into account that this website is not intended for 3D printing.

**6. 3D Warehouse**

The 3D Warehouse simply screams ‘geometrical’. Whether you are looking for architecture, product design or scale models, 3D Warehouse offers anything that was created with the popular 3D modeling software SketchUp. Luckily they also let you filter their database for 3D printable models by selecting ‘Only Show Printable Models’ in their advanced search function. All other models can be made printable thanks to a connection with the 3DPrintCloud.

**7. CGTrader**

CGTrader offers a dedicated database for 3D printable objects. So far there are more than 13,000 models to choose from. We noticed that there are many printable jewelry designs in particular on this website. While many models are downloadable for free, others come at affordable prices.

**8. TurboSquid**

TurboSquid is the place to be for downloading the most stunning 3D designs. It doesn’t get any more high-end and professional than this. The problems: the designs are great visually but are not optimized for 3D printing. There is also no filtering option for finding 3D printable models. Furthermore, all models on TurboSquid are premium (payable) files. Quality comes at a price.

**9. 3DExport**

3DExport is somewhat similar to TurboSquid: This is also a database that focuses on the visual aspects and offers amazing premium 3D models. In addition to this, 3DExport offers its users a filter for finding 3D printable models only.

**10. Yeggi**

Last but not least we want to mention Yeggi, a search engine for 3D printable models. Yeggi scans all the databases mentioned above, and many more, for 3D printable files. So if you want to search the ‘Google’ of 3D models, this might be the right website for you.

**11. Remix 3D**

Remix 3D is more than a 3D model database, is the Microsoft community of modelers who want to share their creations. The models on the libraries are organized by categories and they can be used and of course “remixed” on Microsoft Paint 3D and their VR/AR app, Mixed Reality.

[source](https://i.materialise.com/blog/en/3d-model-databases/)

Comment: Do these offer programmatic APIS for access

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm a fan of Google Poly and I won't accept a substitute yet so I'm not fully informed on APIS, but you can check with another research

Comment: I'm unable to find 3D model APIs that work with Unity...